# Не работает flex end

Tags: html, css3, flexbox

Не могу `.list` разместить в конце с помощью `flex-end`
И ещё при наведении на бургер можно нажать только на один из бордеров

```css
.header {
  max-width: 1261px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;

  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.list li a {
  color: #000;
}

.burger_menu::before {
  content: "";
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.burger_menu {
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
}

.burger_menu::after {
  content: "";
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">    
      <a href="#" class="burger_menu"></a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: а в конце чего Вы пытаетесь разместить .list? flex-end у Вас задан для дочерних элементов .list, сам лист внутри header по умолчанию выровнен по левому краю

Comment: Задайте для класа header display:flex и justify-content: space-between + я так понял что на десктопах нужно скрыть бургер, так задайте ему display:none

Comment: @GGO
- На счёт бургера не так немного) У меня получилось три разных элемента и не знаю как соединить в один, без иконок и оставив при этом before after

Comment: как правило list и burger дают обёртку тегом nav и тогда раскидывают флексами по краям

Answer (score 1):

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: OpenSans, 'sans-serif';
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.header {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.header__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__container > * + * {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.list__item a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.list__item + .list__item {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.burger_menu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.burger__line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  --size: 6px;
}

.burger__line:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(var(--size));
}

.burger__line:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(calc( -1 * var(--size)));
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__container">

      <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="Logo"></a>
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="list__item">
          <a href="#">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <a href="#">О нас</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <a href="#">Контакты</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="burger_menu">
        <div class="burger__line"></div>
        <div class="burger__line"></div>
        <div class="burger__line"></div>
      </a>

    </div> <!-- .header__container -->
  </div> <!-- .container -->
</header>
```